# Python Multiprocessing: How to make Pool and Manager work together?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am trying to understand how `Pool()` and `Manager()` can be combined in Python's multiprocessing library for having shared objects between the individual worker processes. In my example, I would like to have a shared list `input_list`, which should be accessable for all worker processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def f(x):
    input_list.append(x)
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    input_list = manager.list()
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(f, range(10))
    print(input_list)
```

However, I get a `NameError: name 'input_list' is not defined`. Any idea why `input_list` is not recognized as a shared object?

Comment: your example works fine when I run on python 3.8. it returns [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1].

Comment: Interesting. I tried with python 3.8.2, still get the same error. Are you also working on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `functools`. The shared list needs to be passed to the worker function as an additional argument:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import functools

def f(x, input_list):
    input_list.append(x)
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    input_list = manager.list()
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(functools.partial(f, input_list=input_list), range(10))
    print(input_list)
```

An exemplary output is then:

```
[0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```